# Multibinding not working - StrokeThickness of paths is unchanged

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding, imultivalueconverter

I have an `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` filled by an `ObservableCollection` of Paths. The Path class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` has a property named `StrokeThickness` :

```
private double _strokeThickness;
public double StrokeThickness
{
    get { return _strokeThickness; }
    set
    {
        _strokeThickness = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StrokeThickness));
    }
}
```

In our ViewModel we have :

```
public ObservableCollection<Path> PathCollection
{
    get { return _pathCollection; }
    set
    {
        _pathCollection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PathCollection));
    }
}
```

And this is my View :

```
<!-- Paths -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Stroke="{Binding Stroke}"
                  Data="{Binding Data}">
                <Path.StrokeThickness>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource    
                        CorrectStrockThiknessConvertor}">
                        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            <Binding Source="{Binding
                                StrokeThickness}"></Binding>
                            <Binding ElementName="RootLayout" 
                                Path="DataContext.ZoomRatio" >
                            </Binding>
                        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Path.StrokeThickness>
            </Path>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="Canvas"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have used a Multibinding Convertor to give me true StrokeThickness based on ZoomRatio. ZoomRatio is being calculated every time map zoomed.

This is my MultiBinding converter :

```
public class CorrectStrockThiknessConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null & values.Length == 2 && (double)values[0] != 0)
        {
            return (double)values[1] / (double)values[0];
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

when I trace this Converter its work fine but every time it's entry data for StrokeThikness is same and it means return value doesn't change StrokeThikness of Paths.

Am I doing something to wrong?

Comment: `Binding.Source` specifies the *instance* of object which will be monitored by the binding. Without specifying `Binding.Path` it monitors directly for instance of *double* (and not `Path` instance hold by observable collection) and this is the problem.

Comment: @Sinatr And then there's also a Binding on the Source, `<Binding Source="{Binding StrokeThickness}">` which should result in a XamlParseException.

Answer (score 2):

The first Binding in the MultiBinding is wrong. It should look like this:

```
<MultiBinding.Bindings>
    <Binding Path="StrokeThickness" />
    <Binding ElementName="RootLayout" Path="DataContext.ZoomRatio" />
</MultiBinding.Bindings>
```

Also check if the property name is correct, as you constantly write `StrokeThikness` instead of `StrokeThickness` in your question.

You should also check your converter code. It seems you are dividing `ZoomRatio` by `StrokeThickness`, which to my understanding should be the other way round.

Comment: I checked my code again , There is no `StrokeThikness` in my code . it is a misspelling in my question's text .  I Changed Xaml code as you said but doesn't work again. Regardless of ZoomRatio's formula ,the problem is return value has no effect on Strokethickness of paths .

Comment: Debug your converter to see if it returns the desired value. Also check the Output Window in Visual Studio for any Binding error messages.